# Table is not creating in MySQL server from Spring JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have written the code. It goes like -

**Here is my GitHub Repo - https://github.com/SuvamNaskar/spring-learn.git**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:2023/student?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=system32
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization= true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

This is my `application.properties` file. I have tried every single thing I knew.

[There is no error in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMp9P.png) <= Click here to view image

[But no table is created. This is in MySQL WorkBench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLwUv.png) <= Click here to view image

I have tried to create the table from Spring JPA into MySQL

My expectation is, when I run the program if the table is not present then it should create the table.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question, do not simply link it in!

Answer (score 1):

change this from "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop" to "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update"

Answer (score 0):

Entity scan is incorrect @EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.springboot.Model"}) . it should be

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"in.suvam.learn"})
```

create-drop – The Hibernate will drop the database after all operations are completed. As per naveen's comment, pls use update